# How to categorize values of data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I am trying to write a code to categorize a data set (from a CSV) based on the value range using the python pandas library. Aggregate functions can be used. But I am struggling on using aggregate functions.

```
    +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
    |Name         | Age         |Region       |Telephone    |Address      |
    +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
    |             |             |             |             |             |
```

I could develop the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.read_csv('5000 Records.csv')

data_frame['age_range'] = pd.cut(data_frame['Age in Yrs.'],
                             bins=[-float('inf'),30,50,float('inf')],
                             labels=['above', 'in between', 'below'])

data_frame = data_frame.groupby(['Region','age_range']).agg(
    {
        'age_range': "count"
    }
)

print(data_frame)
```

but the result is as follows

```
                      age_range
Region    age_range            
Midwest   above             312
          in between        695
          below             390
Northeast above             201
          in between        421
          below             219
South     above             435
          in between        983
          below             452
West      above             211
          in between        443
          below             238
```

But the requirement is to get the output as:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|Region       | above         |in between |below        |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |             |             |
```

Can somebody please help me in doing this? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Hi UpaniK, could you show a sample of your pre-groupby data?

Comment: age column was filled with float values between 18-60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with simplify `groupby` solution - removed `agg` and added [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html).

[`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) is used for count with exclude missing values, here both solution working same, because `age_range` is used for `by` parameter in `groupby`:

```
df = data_frame.groupby(['Region','age_range']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(data_frame['Region'], data_frame['age_range'])
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the response!!! But It is getting error. `KeyError: 'count'`

Comment: `ValueError: 'age_range' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.` Now it giving this error

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm bit behind of the required knowledge set. So i'm lost middle of thi error

Answer (score 0):

Try `DataFrame.pivot` method:

```
data_frame.pivot(index='Region', columns='age_range', values='count')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. `ValueError: 'age_range' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.` this error has occurred when this method executed!